# Java: Convert an InputStream to an OutputStream

Tags: java, properties, inputstream, outputstream

I'm attempting to extend java.util.Properties so that when the properties file is written the entire file is encrypted. This I have a POC working, and seems easy enough to do.

In addition, I'm trying to make it so that when a non-encrypted properties file is read, it is immediately written back out as an encrypted properties file. This I'm having a more difficult time with.

Since the "load" method of the java.util.Properties only passes in an InputStream, I need some mechanism to turn the InputStream into an OutputStream to send the encrypted content to.

Is this possible to do, or is there no way to get an Outputstream from an InputStream?

Comment: Convert it to string type object from inputStream and then convert this string to Output String.

Comment: Same thing like reading from one file (using inputstream) and writing that content into another file (using outputstream), no ?

Comment: The problem isn't the reading in and writing out. That part I know how to do. The problem is having the writing out to the same location as the InputStream, from within the java.util.properties extended store(InputStream) method where the ONLY input I have is the InputStream. As a result I don't immediately know where the InputStream is pointed, and that's what I need to create the outputstream to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving the values from the InputStream into a string, and then using the java.util.Properties `store` method to write that data into an encrypted properties file.

Comment: Yes, but how do I create the outputstream to the same location as the inputstream, when all I have in the extended java.util.properties is the inputstream? That is the question at hand. It might in fact be impossible, but that is what I'm asking someone to confirm.